# how to calculate kubernetes s pod cpu and memory share rate

Tags: kubernetes

I want to know the share of resource - cpu, memory- per kubernetes's pod. 
And I want to know what the standard of share is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reserve a time to read the  [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and also visit theses links to know [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)  and [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**]. Please give more details about your issue, and give examples if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to do using kubectl only (or I don't know how). What we usually do is to use the kubelet metric-server to export all metric to prometheus. We then use Grafana to calculate those values. The following metrics should allow you to calculate your values:

CPU cores:

- kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores - available cores
- kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores - requested cores per container
- container_cpu_usage_seconds_total - used cores per container

Memory:

- kube_node_status_allocatable_memory_bytes - available memory
- kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes - requested memory by container
- container_memory_usage_bytes - used memory by container

You can filter those by label (i.e. by pod name or namespace) and calculate all kinds of things based on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try `kubectl top` and friends. More words because SO requires them.

Comment: I already checked the kubectl top pod.  I only saw resource usage. 
But, I want to know the pod's cpu, memory share.
Also, I wonder what is the denominator when calculating CPU and memory share.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the total resources? You can find that via `kubectl describe node` on each node.

Comment: I checked kubectl describe node, I can check cpu request, limited and memory request, limited per pod.
Also, the kubectl describe pod cannot see the resource usage and share of the pod.
I am wondering what percentage of the pod's resources occupy. And, is pod resource share based on node?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) which is the Cluster-wide aggregator of resource usage data. It is the source of container resource metrics for Kubernetes built-in autoscaling pipelines. It collects resource metrics from Kubelets and exposes them in Kubernetes apiserver. You can also access the metrics API by `kubectl top`.

Another solution is using Prometheus as suggested by @jankantert.